# js code not working in Endeca

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, endeca, jplist

So I have some code that I've tested locally, in jsfiddle and codepen. It all works fine. When I put the code into endeca though and test on my staging environment, the dropdown fields do not show up at all.

I've moved the script tags around, I've tried hosting the file somewhere else, I've removed the additional scripts on the page, I've even pasted all of the code in and not linked externally and nothing worked.

Here is the link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/lfi809/pen/RLgQoB). Any kind of help would be great (I would provide a link to the page but its on a secure environment and can only be viewed at work). I have also included the code below, oh! It's also using JPList if that helps anything

```
/*jplist panel*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mkt-gallery").jplist({
        itemsMGbox: '.list',
        itemPath: '.list-item',
        panelPath: '.jplist-panel',
        storage: 'localstorage',
        storageName: 'mixed-controls-local-storage'
    });
});

/*modal*/
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex - 1].alt;
}
```

Comment: Can you see any errors on browser console ?

Comment: yes, the only thing it shows me is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at showSlides (mktgallery4.js:180)
    at mktgallery4.js:157
showSlides @ mktgallery4.js:180
(anonymous) @ mktgallery4.js:157
mktgallery4.js:144 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jplist is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (mktgallery4.js:144)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: `mktgallery4` is a JS plugin?

Comment: its using code from a plugin called JPList combined with custom code at the bottom of the file